# Basic login system Symfony

Tags: symfony, security

I'm trying to build a basic login system with Symfony3 using my database. But everytimes I put correct credentials, I always got

```
Invalid credentials.
Bad credentials.
```

I don't know why.

Herey are my codes :

login.html.twig

```
 {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="container-fluid" style="width: 400px">
        <h2>Please Sign In</h2>
        {% if error %}
            <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
        {% endif %}
<form class="form-signin" method='post' action='{{path('login_check')}}'>
    {% if error %}
        <div class='red'>{{ error.message }}</div><br>
    {% endif %}
    <label for="inputName" class="sr-only">User Name</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name='_username' class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password"  class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Connection</button>
</form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

SecurityController

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
       // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('Security/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
        //return $this->render('F3ILCocktailBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

security.yml

```
  security:

  firewalls:

    authentification:
      anonymous: true
      form_login:
        check_path: login_check
        default_target_path: admin_recette_new
        login_path: login
      logout:
        path: logout
        target: /login
      pattern: ^/

    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false

    login:
      pattern: ^/login
      security: false

    main:
      anonymous: true
      pattern: ^/admin
      provider: our_db_provider

  providers:
    in_memory:
      memory: ~
    our_db_provider:
      entity:
        class: "F3ILCocktailBundle:User"
        property: email

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

  encoders:
    F3ILCocktailBundle\Entity\User:
      algorithm: bcrypt
      cost: 12
```

routing.yml

```
   f3_il_cocktail:
    resource: "@F3ILCocktailBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

login.:
    path: /login
    defaults: { _controller: F3ILCocktailBundle:Security:login}

login_check:
    path: /login_check

logout:
    path:   /logout
```

Once connected, I want the user to go on the route `admin_recette_new`, but nothing is work. Always got :

```
Invalid credentials,
Bad credentials.
```

Even when all the credentials are correct. Please what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The input field name for sending the username should be `_username` and not `_email`

Comment: I just changed ` email ` into ` _username ` and got the EXACT same problem :(